# MPI - Непонятное поведение простой программы

Tags: c++, mpi, c

Изучаю MPI, написал простую программу:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main (argc, argv)
     int argc;
     char *argv[];
{
  int rank, size;

  int int_array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
  int* p_int;

  float float_array[5] = {1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5};
  float* p_float;

  char char_array[5] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
  char* p_char;

  p_int = &int_array[0];
  p_float = &float_array[0];
  p_char = &char_array[0];

  MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  if(rank == 0){
    MPI_Send(p_int, 5, MPI_INT, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(p_float, 5, MPI_FLOAT, 1, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Send(p_char, 6, MPI_CHAR, 1, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  } else{
    int* p_int_r;
    float* p_float_r;
    char* p_char_r;

    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Recv(p_int_r, 5, MPI_INT, 0, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
    printf("Programm has received an array: %d,%d,%d,%d,%d \n", 
    *(p_int_r + 0), *(p_int_r + 1), 
    *(p_int_r + 2), *(p_int_r + 3), *(p_int_r + 4));
    MPI_Recv(p_float_r, 5, MPI_FLOAT, 0, 2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
    printf("Programm has received an array: %g,%g,%g,%g,%g \n", 
    *(p_float_r + 0), *(p_float_r + 1), 
    *(p_float_r + 2), *(p_float_r + 3), *(p_float_r + 4));
    MPI_Recv(p_char_r, 6, MPI_CHAR, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status); 
    printf("Programm has received an array: %c,%c,%c,%c,%c \n", 
    *(p_char_r + 0), *(p_char_r + 1), 
    *(p_char_r + 2), *(p_char_r + 3), *(p_char_r + 4));
  }  
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

При запуске программы, во время приема массива символов, падала ошибка MPI_ERR_BUFFER: invalid buffer pointer. Решил проблему путем исправления строки `char* p_char_r;` на `char* p_char_r=malloc(6);`.

Не могу понять почему не работало до исправления и почему ошибка появляется только при приеме массива символов?

Comment: Программу на полторы тысячи символов сложно назвать простой.

Comment: Писать что-то в неинициализированные указатели вообще ужасно. Не упало сейчас (это я про указатели на float/int), упадёт потом - но будет куда хуже.

Comment: @m0nhawk Похоже, я что-то не понимаю.  Я не вижу, где что-либо пишется в указатели вообще.  Я вижу, где указатель устанавливается на конкретный адрес памяти.

Comment: @AleksG `MPI_Recv` пишет в `*p_int_r`, `*p_float_r` и `*p_char_r`.

Comment: @m0nhawk А! Я просто пропустил половину кода :) гы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI тут ни при чем.  Проблема в том, что года Вы получаете данные, Вы записываете их в соответствующие буфера в памяти.  Однако Вы нигде не выделили память под эти данные.  Поэтому при попытке сохранения данных в буфер система пытается их писать неизвестно куда.

Когда же Вы выделили память при помощи `malloc` - то дальше есть выделенное место в памяти, куда можно писать данные.

То, что это ошибка произошла при получении char[] - это просто случайность.  Проблема присутствует при получении всех трех типов данных.  Сейчас сработало - в следующий раз нет.  Поэтому нужно выделить память под эти данные:

```
int* p_int_r = malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
float* p_float_r = malloc(5 * sizeof(float));
char* p_char_r = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
```

И на забудьте в конце программы освободить всю эту память:

```
free(p_int_r);
free(p_float_r);
free(p_char_r);
```